# How can I scrape the image using Beautiful Soup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapinghub

I am trying to scrape the image link from the below link but I am not able to

Link : https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/rewards/citi-rewards-credit-card?eOfferCode=INCCCCTWAFCTRELM

I have used the below code

```
x = ' https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/rewards/citi-rewards-credit-card?eOfferCode=INCCCCTWAFCTRELM'
html = urlopen(x)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('div', class_ = "m-top-sm block-hero-art-2 display-image"))
```

Output:

```
<img _ngcontent-c11="" alt="Citi Logo" class="logo" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://www.cdn.citibank.com/v1/ingcb/cbol/files/images/logos/logo.png?_bust=2021-01-21T05-05-29-195Z"/>
```

**But this is a wrong link in src that I am getting and it is not the image link.**

The highlighted part in the HTML code is where the image link resides.
I'd be glad if I get the right code to scrape the image link.

[image: Image to be scraped with the tag]

Which tag should be used so that get that exact image link ?

Could any one help me with the alternate code with which I could get the desired result ?

Comment: This card image is added dynamically by JS so `bs4` doesn't see this in the source `HTML`. In other words, just turn JavaScript off on that site and see what *actually* is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per @baduker comment card image is added  dynamically by JS so bs4 doesn't see this in the source HTML.so  you should  try [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) with bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
x = ' https://www.online.citibank.co.in/credit-card/rewards/citi-rewards-credit-card?eOfferCode=INCCCCTWAFCTRELM'
wb = webdriver.Chrome()
wb.get(x)

soup = BeautifulSoup(wb.page_source, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('div', class_ = "m-top-sm block-hero-art-2 display-image"))
print(soup.find('div', class_ = "m-top-sm block-hero-art-2 display-image").find('img').get('src'))
```

To install selenium, run this in your terminal or follow the above link.

```
pip install selenium
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hari\PycharmProjects\Card_Prj\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`  Above code gave me this error.

Comment: follow https://www.easeus.com/resource/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified.html

Comment: Can't I get the desired result by just using beautiful soup ?

Comment: yes, you need selenium to get the dynamic content

Comment: I followed your advice and now I am able to scrape the image links. Thanks a lot!!!